# 03 Accord V6 6spd Motor swap No Start

Tags: honda, accord, no-crank-no-start

I just swapped in a used j3a4 v6 with 110,000 after throwing a rod in my last one. Everything is plugged in and I have a no start condition that seems to be related to the starter. The battery is good and when i test voltage to starter it also shows power but the secondary wire has no power. I direct wired the starter and the starter is fine but I have been unable to figure out why the secondary wite isnt getting any power. Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

03 Accord v6 6spd

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the green key lit up on the dash?

Comment: When i turn the car to accessory its on for a second and goes away. Also when i go to remove the key the green key blinks three times then goes away. Its not solid though.

Comment: That seems normal to me. I was wondering if the security system was causing you issues. Next thing to check are the relays. I believe there should be one for the starter circuit (to energize the solenoid). It would be in the under hood fuse box.